# Ionic2 App, File does not exist

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

```
openFile(){
    console.log("openfile");
    this.fileOpener.open('/assets/hello', 'application/rtf')
  .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error openening file', e));
  }
```

I want to open that rtf file which is in assets folder in my app.
I have used File Opener plugin.
Now when i'm running app i got Error openening file – `{status: "9", message: "File does not exist"}`.

Comment: try  `this.fileOpener.open('assets/hello.rtf', 'application/rtf')`

Comment: I tried that also, but same error.

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to open files like "assets/*" with FileOpener. FileOpener needs a real file path.